# XMLWriter cannot access file that it just created

Tags: c#, xml, io

I have a service that is processing data and exporting out xml files for another service, which usually handles small amount of data(About 5 files a minute) but sometimes a large chunk of data is dumped and it may handle needing to create 100 files all at once.

The service runs mostly fine but it occasionally runs into an error:
    `The process cannot access the file 'C:\File.xml' because it is being used by another process.`

This is strange because the file should be created, written, and closed all in one shot, so I don't know what could be giving this problem.  The issue seems to happen more frequently under heavy load, but still occurs regularly under light loads as well. Naturally this never shows up while debugging or I probably would have fixed this by now.

Here is the function that actually writes the file:

```
public bool WriteDocument(Object Data)
{
     XmlDocument X = new XmlDocument();
     XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
     schemaSet.Add(null, "Schema.xsd");
     X.Schemas = schemaSet;         

     if (!Directory.Exists("OutputDirectory"))
     {          
           Directory.CreateDirectory("OutputDirectory");
     }

     string File = Path.Combine("OutputDirectory", @"File" + ".xml");
     XmlSerializer Encoder = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Object));

     //Do stuff to data object to prepare for output

     using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream())
     {
         Encoder.Serialize(buffer, Data);

         buffer.Position = 0;
         X.Load(buffer);
         X.Validate((sender, e) =>
         {
              if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
              {
                   result = false;
              }
              else
              {
                   result = true;
              }
         });
     }
     if (result)
     {
          while (System.IO.File.Exists(File))
          {
               File = MakeUniqueName(File);
          }
          XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
          settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

          using (XmlWriter Writer = XmlWriter.Create(File, settings))
          {
              X.WriteTo(Writer);
              Writer.Close();
          }
     }

     return result;
}
```

Comment: Wrap things like `MemoryStream` in a using, do you don't have to manually close the instance

Comment: What happens if the 2nd process is reading while the 1st is trying to write?  A simple solution if for the 2nd process to create a temp file before reading and deleting the temp file when done. First process can ten wait for temp file to be deleted or ignore temp file if it is older than 5 seconds.

Comment: You need to bracket the `XmlWriter` in a `using` statement, e.g. `using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(File, settings)) { X.WriteTo(writer); }`  If `WriteTo()` were somehow throwing an exception (e.g. because of lack of disk space) then the file would never get closed.

Comment: @jdweng - I'm not sure what this second process is and don't have control over it. From my point of view, these files are written, closed, then left in a folder and ignored. I trying to figure out how to lock the file until after I am done writing it.

Comment: I've added the using blocks, even though they don't fix this issue. just because I agree that it's good practice

Comment: In windows you can't write a file that is opened by another process.  You could put an exception handle in the write so that you can wait and try again when it fails.

Comment: @jdweng - I very well understand that only one process can normally write to a file, I trying to figure out how to prevent another process from snatching the file away before I have even had a chance to finish creating it.

Comment: You can't without a modification to the other process.  If the denial is only for a short period of time  retry until you can do the write.